# 16.04 clang: bad selection of gcc toolchain

Tags: 16.04, compiling, c++, clang

I have two 16.04 systems with gcc (5.4.0 and 6.0.0) and clang 3.8 (1:3.8-33ubuntu3.1). On the first system, clang succeeds compiling C++ code; with adding -v, essential output parts are:

```
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
[...]
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5.4.0
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

But, on another system, it fails; verbose output shows

```
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
```

But GCC6 in this version doesn't contain headers, so compilation fails:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
In file included from TimeHelper.cc:1:
./TimeHelper.hh:4:10: fatal error: 'cstdint' file not found
#include <cstdint>
```

The header is present in `/usr/include/c++/5/` but this path is not listed here. (libstdc++-5-dev is installed.)

Systems are not identical but both brand fresh (updated today).

How to find out what is the issue source?

Is the preferred toolchain hardwired or suggested in a config file?

NB attempt to explicitly specify `--gcc-toolchain` to a value like `/usr/lib/gcc/x86-64-linux-gnu/5` fails: it seems clang doesn't recognize the directory as a GCC installation path. Unlike it, to specify target directory of a manual GCC build succeeds (but I want to see it working by default).

Comment: Wondering whether this is really a question for a C/C++ forum as opposed to for AskUbuntu?

Comment: @JuanAntonio I don't think so. Neither my system (FreeBSD, CentOS) has such issue, it seems to be very specific to Ubuntu build of clang.

Comment: @JuanAntonio no, this is fine here. It isn't really about C itself, but about compiling something on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed after installing clang 4.0 (this didn't fix the issue by itself), removing rests of clang 3.8, gccgo, and reinstalling GCC 5 from the same packages. Now it selects the proper version.

Due to lack of select algorithm details I can't say exactly what of them caused this result. Anyway, it works.

Answer (score 0):

On the machine that works:

```
$ find /usr/include/c++/ -name cstdint
/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/cstdint
/usr/include/c++/5/cstdint
$ dpkg -S /usr/include/c++/5/cstdint
libstdc++-5-dev:amd64: /usr/include/c++/5/cstdint
```

So it's in `libstdc++-5-dev`.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libstdc++-5-dev

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libstdc++-5-dev/filelist

Let's look into `libstdc++-6-dev` then:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libstdc++-6-dev

http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/arm64/libstdc++-6-dev/filelist

```
...
/usr/include/c++/6/cstdint
...
...
/usr/include/c++/6/tr1/cstdint
...
```

Comment: yep, libstdc++-5-dev installed on both hosts. I don't treat installing packages from a newer flavor as a solution.

Comment: So why do you have packages from a newer flavor on the second machine?

Comment: I haven't. There is no libstdc++-6-dev. There are gcc-6-base:{amd64,i386} that are stock in xenial.